# GetFeatureCount gives same result after deleting a feature

Tags: python, gdal, layers, ogr, features

This is my code:

```
num1 = layer.GetFeatureCount()
layer.DeleteFeature(1)
layer.SyncToDisk()
num2 = layer.GetFeatureCount()
print num1
print num2
```

For some reason, num1 and num2 are the same number. Why? Shouldn't deleting the feature make the FeatureCount smaller by 1?

Comment: Layer is probably stored to memory, try reloading the layer variable

Comment: Nothing changed, same result

Comment: Do you have a feature with ID=1? If you do not, nothing gets deleted. Otherwise it looks like you are doing the same as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950627/how-to-delete-feature-from-shapefile-using-gdal-c which was said to work.

Answer (score 7):

It's because the OGR `layer.DeleteFeature(fid)` method doesn't *actually* delete features, it just marks them as deleted in the .dbf then ignores them. This is mentioned in the [shapefile driver doc](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/shapefile.html):

> Deleted shapes are marked for deletion in the .dbf file, and then
>   ignored by OGR. To actually remove them permanently (resulting in
>   renumbering of FIDs) invoke the SQL 'REPACK ' via the
>   datasource ExecuteSQL() method.

What the doc doesn't say is why `GetFeatureCount` still returns the same number after the "delete".  According to the (current) main developer, it's because iterating over all features to recount is [potentially expensive](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2011-June/028938.html):

> Yes, the GetFeatureCount() implementation of OGRShapeLayer returns the
>   number  of records, both the valid and invalid ones. To get the number
>   of features (=  valid records), it would have to iterate over each
>   record, which is a  potentially lengthy operation.

To get the correct number of features:

```
yourdatasource.ExecuteSQL('repack yourlayername')
```

This won't be as big an issue in [GDAL 2.2 as](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/shapefile.html):

> Starting with GDAL 2.2, REPACK is also done automatically at file
>   closing, or at FlushCache()/SyncToDisk() time, since shapefiles with
>   holes can cause interoperability issues with other software.

BUT note [this bug report](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/6672) if you are on Windows (fixed in GDAL 2.1.2):

> **Shapefile REPACK cause corruptions on Windows**
>
> ...the current behaviour of REPACK that attempts to delete the existing .dbf, .shp, .shx and
>   rename the _packed.dbf, ... as .dbf, .shp, .shx fails because there
>   might be still file descriptors open on the .dbf, .shp, .shx in the
>   current process or in other processes. The only reliable solution in
>   this case is to modify in place the content of the files.