# Deleting selected features from Vector/OGR in GDAL/Python?

Tags: python, gdal, ogr

I run the following code to first select specific attributes using a query and then I need to delete them

```
from osgeo import gdal, ogr
import os

##shapefile = "D:/New.shp"
##driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
##dataSource = driver.Open(shapefile, 0)

shapefile = ogr.Open( "D:/New.shp")

layer = shapefile.GetLayer()
layer.SetAttributeFilter("Area < 5000")

for i in layer:
    print i.GetField("Area")
    layer.DeleteFeature(i)
```

I get the following error :

```
layer.DeleteFeature(i)   File
"C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\osgeo\ogr.py", line 1499, in
DeleteFeature
return _ogr.Layer_DeleteFeature(self, *args) TypeError: not an integer
```

I changed the last line of my code to ogr.Layer_DeleteFeature(i) to which i get the error

```
ogr.layer_DeleteFeature(i)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'layer_DeleteFeature'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're passing a [`Feature`](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Feature-class.html) object to [`layer.DeleteFeature`](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Layer-class.html#DeleteFeature) which is expecting an integer value (a feature ID or "FID"), not a Feature object.

Try passing the [FID](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Feature-class.html#GetFID) instead:

```
for feat in layer:
    print feat.GetField("Area")
    layer.DeleteFeature(feat.GetFID())
```

Note that the OGR `layer.DeleteFeature(fid)` method doesn't *actually* delete features, it just marks them as deleted in the .dbf then ignores them. This is mentioned in the [shapefile driver doc](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/shapefile.html):

> Deleted shapes are marked for deletion in the .dbf file, and then
>   ignored by OGR. To actually remove them permanently (resulting in
>   renumbering of FIDs) invoke the SQL 'REPACK ' via the
>   datasource ExecuteSQL() method.

For more info, see [GetFeatureCount gives same result after deleting a feature](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/220236/2856).

Comment: this runs the code without any error and prints the selected features, but i want it to edit my shapefile which it doesnt

Comment: @Basil https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/220236/2856

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I mean, it doesn't delete the features I previously selected

Comment: @ilFonta have you repacked your dataset? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/220236/2856

Comment: I did it. I tried any possible combination. Like this layerVec.SetAttributeFilter("pol = '0'")
layerVec.ResetReading()

for i in range(0, layerVec.GetFeatureCount()):
    layerVec.ResetReading()
    feature = layerVec.GetNextFeature()
    layerVec.DeleteFeature(feature.GetFID())
 fileVec.ExecuteSQL('REPACK ' + layerVec.GetName())
 fileVec.ExecuteSQL('RECOMPUTE EXTENT ON ' + layerVec2.GetName())

Comment: Then ask a new question. Showing exactly what you did and mentioning this answer.

Comment: @ilFonta i am having the same problems trying to delete features from a .gdb. Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

It works using that code:

```
shapefile = ogr.Open(file.shp, 1)
layer = shapefile.GetLayer()
layer.SetAttributeFilter("Area < 5000")

for feat in layer:
    print feat.GetField("Area")
    layer.DeleteFeature(feat.GetFID())
    shapefile.ExecuteSQL('REPACK ' + layer.GetName())
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I'm not sure I properly used all the instructions in the correct way

```
fileVec = ogr.Open(pathMaskVec, True)
layerVec = fileVec.GetLayer()

layerVec.SetAttributeFilter("pol = '0'")

for i in range(0, layerVec.GetFeatureCount()):
    layerVec.ResetReading()
    feature = layerVec.GetNextFeature()
    layerVec.DeleteFeature(feature.GetFID())
    fileVec.ExecuteSQL('REPACK ' + layerVec.GetName())
    fileVec.ExecuteSQL('RECOMPUTE EXTENT ON ' + layerVec.GetName())
```